# How to select elements from an already selected element object with splash

Tags: jquery, lua, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

After selecting an element using `splash:select` how do you then select all the anchor elements found as children under it?

I have tried this `lua` script with scrapy/splash:

```
function main(splash)
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(0.9))

    local classlist = splash:select('.class-list')        
    local alinks = classlist:select_all('a')

    return {alinks=alinks}

end
```

But I get the following bad request to Splash error:

```
{
    u'info':{
        u'line_number':12,
        u'message':        u'Lua error:[
            string "..."
        ]:12:attempt to call method \'select_all\' (a nil value)',
        u'type':u'LUA_ERROR',
        u'source':u'        [
            string "..."
        ]        ', u'        error':u"attempt to call method 'select_all' (a nil value)"
    },
    u'type':u'ScriptError',
    u'description':u'Error happened while executing Lua script',
    u'error':400
}
```

I have confirmed that the `splash:select('.class-list')` returns a valid element object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, `splash:select('.class-list')` returns a valid element object. Your problem is that element objects [don't have a select_all method](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-element-object.html#methods); only the [splash object does](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-select-all). Instead you need to use `splash:select_all` with a different selector. Try the following (though beware, as it is untested).

```
function main(splash)
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(0.9))
    local alinks = splash:select_all('.class-list a')        
    return {alinks=alinks}
end
```